# C# CS0079 Event Handling Compile Error

Tags: c#, .net, events, compiler-errors

I got CS0079 compile error when I tried to run the code below:

```
public delegate void MyClassEHandler(MyClassEParam param);

public class MyClassE
{
    public static event MyClassEHandler Error
    {
         add
         {
              MyClassE.Error = (MyClassEHandler)Delegate.Combine(MyClassE.Error, value);
         } 
    }
}
```

Error:

> CS0079 : The event `MyClassE.Error` can only appear on the left hand
>   side of += or -=

Searched around but couldn't figure out how to resolve it.

ADDED:
    if (MyClass.Error != null) or
    MyClass.Error(null, null);

Get the same CS0079 error.

> CS0079 : The event `MyClassE.Error` can only appear on the left hand
>   side of += or -=

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Is this code part of `MyClassE` class or some other one?

Comment: yes, this code is part of MyClassE class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set an event, you can just add or remove handlers on it. So, as the error says, you should just do:

```
public delegate void MyClassEHandler(MyClassEParam param);

public static event MyClassEHandler Error
{
     add
     {
          MyClassE.Error += value;
     } 
     remove         
     {
          MyClassE.Error -= value;
     } 
}
```

and the `Delegate.Combine` will work magically for you.

Comment: Also it needs `remove` accessors.

Comment: Added, it's kinda implied, but this way is better :)

Comment: I meant that you do not need to explicitly call `Delegate.Combine` as in your snippet, you just do a += and the new handler is added to the invocation list.

Comment: if (MyClass.Error != null) or MyClass.Error(null, null);
gives me the same error. any idea?

Comment: waitaminute, in the add handler, are you assigning to the same event that the handler is defined in? That won't work, take a look at the [description for the `add ` accessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713648.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public delegate void MyClassEHandler(MyClassEParam param);  
static MyClassEHandler error;

public static event MyClassEHandler Error
{
 add
 {
      MyClassE.error += (MyClassEHandler)Delegate.Combine(MyClassE.Error, value);
 } 

 remove
 {
      MyClassE.Error -= (MyClassEHandler)Delegate.Combine(MyClassE.Error, value);
 } 

}
```

Refer to the [Intercepting add remove of c# event and delegates](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/25/intercepting-add-and-remove-of-c-event-delegates/)